# R: gWidgets2: the development version in Windows seems to fail in installation

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the development version of gWidgets2 in a WIndows XP system.
Unfortunately when I'm running

```
require(devtools)
install_github("gWidgets2", username="jverzani")
install_github("gWidgets2RGtk2", username="jverzani")
```

the tar.gz file is downloaded and not the zip windows version.

```
> building 'gWidgets2RGtk2_1.0.tar.gz'
```

So I downloaded manually the jverzani-gWidgets2-79fd592.zip file from https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/downloads and I tried to install the package locally. But then I receive

```
> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
```

and the file is not installed.

The same happens with gWidgets2tcltk, gWidgetsWWW2, gWidgets2 and gWidgets2RGtk2.

Is there anybody who has tried to do the same ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Send me an email with contact info and I'll build a package through win-builder. --John

Comment: Tried this under windows xp from within RStudio and it all installed fine. Not sure why you can't, but I used the latest Rtools and R, if that helps.

Comment: Did you try the install_url() function in devtools directly on the link to the .ta.gz file or install() also in devtools on the downloaded file?